# When is the logarithm of this function square integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I was trying to prove $\log(1-|r(s)|^2)$ lies in $L^2$ when $r\in L^1\cap L^2$. How should I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find that? How far did you get?

Comment: Do you have any question regarding my answer?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, did you mean $f_1\circ r$ or $f_2\circ r$, where $$f_1(x)=\log(1+|x|^2)\text{ and }f_2(x)=\log(1-x^2)?$$

Note that $f_1\circ r$ is defined everywhere, whereas the function 
$$f_2\circ r(s)=\log(1-|r(s)|^2)=\log(1+|r(s)|)+\log(1-|r(s)|)$$ has meaning only when $|r(s)|<1$ [*].

Now, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous (Borel measurable will do) hence, under the restriction [*], $f_k\circ r$ is Lebesgue measurable $k=1,2$.

Hence to prove $f_k\circ r\in L^2$, it suffice to find some estimate of the form $$|f_k(x)|\leq C x\tag{1$_k$}$$

To reach (1$_1$) we use $1<1+x^2\leq1+2x+x^2=(1+x)^2$ for $x>0$, and hence 
$$0\leq f_1(x)=\log(1+x^2)=2\log(1+x)\leq 2x$$
where in the last step we used the (sort of) standard estimate $\log(1+x)\leq x$ (to prove that, consider the sign of the derivative of $x\mapsto\log(1+x)-x$ and check the value at $x=0$).

For (1$_2$), however, we have $1-x^2<0$ for $|x|<1$ and hence
$$|f_2(x)|=\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\leq x-\log(1-x)$$
and the function 
$$x\mapsto-\log(1-x)\tag{2}$$ 
blows up at $x=1$...

(2) suggest it is time to search for a counterexample, that is we look for $r\in L^1\cap L^2$ with say $0<r<1$ and 
$$\log(1-|r(x)|)\notin L^2$$
To construct such a function, a good start is $r(x)=1-\exp(-f(x))$ with $f(x)>0$, because then $0<r(x)<1$ and $$-\log(1-r(x))=f(x)$$
Now the idea is that

- $f$ should decay to $0$ slow enough so that $f\notin L^1\cap L^2$
- while in the same time $\exp(-f(x))$ is close enough to $1$ making $r\in L^1\cap L^2$.

---

> The choice $f(x)=1/x^2$ leads to $r(x)= 1-\exp(-1/x^2)$, this function stays very close to 1, around $x=0$, and $\log(1-r(x))=-1/x^2$ is not integrable. However, $r$ is continuous and has decays enough to be in $L^p,\,p\geq 1$.

---

**(If you hold the mouse pointer in the grey area above you will see a counterexample.)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have to apologize that I forgot to include the condition $|r|<1$. So what do you think now? COuld you help me?

Comment: And also, it was $f_2$ in your definition that I am considering.

Comment: Fine, well I tried to give a method how to argue with these kind of problems, when it works and when it doesn't work. In the end, it was not possible to find sufficient estimate of the function - and then I tried to show how to argue when we look for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for instance that $|\log(1+\delta)|\leq2\delta$ for all $\delta$.